# Text size changes when I turn it horizontally?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I created a simple `Text` on scene. [image]When I change resolution to **1080x1920** it changes  its the size.[image] . As you can see in second picture text size lower than first So how can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

click on the canvas in the hierarchy, than change in the inspector the size mode (i forgot it's name in unity) , and choose physical size, or something else, and tweak the scaling to 0.5,so the text will be scaled with the screen resolution changes, hope it fix ur issue